# Flutter - how to store a list in GetStorage?

Tags: list, flutter, sharedpreferences

For each article the user browses, I want to save the ID information.
I am using getstorage my code sample is below.

I can not find a true way also, i am looking best way to save id's list.

```
    final box = GetStorage();
  List<String> myFavoriteList = [];

  saveFav(String id) {
    myFavoriteList.add(id);
    box.write('favoriteArticles', myFavoriteList.cast<String>());
  }

  ifExistInFav(String id) async {
    bool ifExists = false;
    List<String> my = (box.read('favoriteArticles').cast<String>() ?? []);
    ifExists = my.contains(id) ? true : false;
    return ifExists;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define your list and convert it to String.

** note that if you use a custom data type ensure you convert your model to String.

then you can use the following to store a List as a String object

```
final box = GetStorage('AppNameStorage');
/// write a storage key's value
saveListWithGetStorage(String storageKey, List<dynamic> storageValue) async => await box.write(/*key:*/ storageKey, /*value:*/ jsonEncode(storageValue));
/// read from storage
readWithGetStorage(String storageKey) => box.read(storageKey);
```

the saving procee implemention:

```
saveList(List<dynamic> listNeedToSave) {
    /// getting all saved data
    String oldSavedData = GetStorageServices().readWithGetStorage('saveList');

/// in case there is saved data
if(oldSavedData != null){
  /// create a holder list for the old data
  List<dynamic> oldSavedList = jsonDecode(oldSavedData);
  
  /// append the new list to saved one
  oldSavedList.addAll(listNeedToSave);
  /// save the new collection
  return GetStorageServices().saveListWithGetStorage('saveList', oldSavedList);
} else{
  /// in case of there is no saved data -- add the new list to storage
  return GetStorageServices().saveListWithGetStorage('saveList', listNeedToSave);
}
}


/// read from the storage
readList() => GetStorageServices().readWithGetStorage('saveList');
```

then the usage:

```
onTap: () async => debugPrint('\n\n\n read list items ${jsonDecode(await readList())}\n\n\n', wrapWidth: 800),
```

Comment: readWithGetStorage() this method returns last added string.

Comment: the given solution does not handle the old saved list, you may retrieve the saved list first and append the now item to it then save the update list to GetStorage.

I going to update it.

Comment: Updated! check and pls let me know if there is any question :)

Comment: the first snippet makes the code harder to understand, please remove saveListWithGetStorage, readWithGetStorage and GetStorageServices, keep the code minimal.